# TSQL Pivot query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, dynamic-sql

I need help on TSQL Pivot and getting error. any help is greatly appreciated.
Below is the query and data.

```
DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(8000),
    @query  AS VARCHAR(8000)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.steps) 
            FROM Tableabc AS c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(8000)') 
        ,1,1,'')
--print @cols
set @query = 'SELECT name, ElapsedTime_Sec,' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select name,ElapsedTime_Sec

                FROM Tableabc
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(steps)
                for ElapsedTime_Sec in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

Table information:

[image: Table Info]

Comment: "Getting error" is really not helpful here. What error are you getting? Any effort you put into making this easy for other people will reap benefits as others are then actually able to help. Converting your image of data into an actual table (create statement and inserts) would be a huge step in the right direction.

Comment: This is my first posting need help to convert image into actual table. Error i am getting is for one of the value for @cols
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'Touch/Stain'.

Comment: you can't have a / in a regular column name. you need to put square brackets around it like [Touch/Stain]

Comment: "Touch/Stain" is not in the picture of sample data you posted. You need to script your table and generate insert statements with data the represent the problem. That way others can run this on their system instead of having to be a human sql parser which is nearly impossible. :) Here is a great article explaining how this can be done. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Another option is go to sqlfiddle.com and create a fiddle.

Comment: you're selecting `max(steps)` in your pivot but not selecting a field named `steps` in your subquery just before the pivot

Comment: there's really nothing logical about the query based on the data so PIVOT might not be what you're actually wanting to do here

Comment: Please add expected output to your question... as it is your question is too light on details.

Answer (score 1):

Without any expected output and a faulty PIVOT query, I'm just guessing as to what you want. But here is a script that works based loosely on your question. I'm guessing it's not the output you want, but you can work from this script and maybe turn it into something you need.

```
CREATE TABLE #Tableabc(ID INT,name VARCHAR(256), Steps VARCHAR(1024),ElapsedTime_Sec INT);

INSERT INTO #Tableabc(ID,name,Steps,ElapsedTime_Sec)VALUES
    (2,'Features','Touch/Stain',25),
    (29,'Shipping','Step requiring QA',129),
    (47,'Behavioral','Gloves',8);

DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(8000),
    @query  AS VARCHAR(8000);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.steps) 
            FROM #Tableabc AS c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(8000)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT * FROM #Tableabc
            pivot 
            (
                 max(ElapsedTime_Sec)
                for Steps in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p ';
execute(@query);

DROP TABLE #Tableabc;
```

Output:

```
+----+------------+--------+-------------------+-------------+
| ID |    name    | Gloves | Step requiring QA | Touch/Stain |
+----+------------+--------+-------------------+-------------+
| 47 | Behavioral | 8      | NULL              | NULL        |
|  2 | Features   | NULL   | NULL              | 25          |
| 29 | Shipping   | NULL   | 129               | NULL        |
+----+------------+--------+-------------------+-------------+
```